# MongoDB expireAfterSeconds / TTL is not deleting data in existing collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with existing data. I added a new index to this collection with the expireAfterSeconds parameter:

```
2015-11-11T09:09:21.565+0100 I INDEX    [conn120] build index on: cmon.cmon.interfaces_history properties: { v: 1, key: { expireAt: 1 }, name: "expireAt_1", ns: "cmon.cmon.interfaces_history", expireAfterSeconds: 1 }
2015-11-11T09:09:21.565+0100 I INDEX    [conn120]    building index using bulk method
2015-11-11T09:09:21.730+0100 I INDEX    [conn120] build index done.  scanned 8933 total records. 0 secs
2015-11-11T09:09:21.733+0100 I COMMAND  [conn120] command cmon.$cmd command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "cmon.interfaces_history", indexes: [ { expireAfterSeconds: 1, name: "expireAt_1", key: { expireAt: 1 } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:113 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1, w: 1 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { w: 17870 }, acquireWaitCount: { w: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { w: 886 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } }, Metadata: { acquireCount: { W: 2 } } } 169ms
```

Then I added a new entry with the *expireAt* value set like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56446521637140e419b881c7"),
"DeviceName" : "mx1",
"updateTime" : ISODate("2015-11-05T11:17:10.000Z"),
"expireAt" : ISODate("2015-11-12T11:10:13.257Z"),
"DomainName" : "domain.net",
"ifAdminStatus" : "up",
"ifName" : "3002",
"ifOperStatus" : "up"
}
```

Existing entries in this collection look exactly the same but do not have *expireAt* set. MongoDB does not delete this entry from the database. When I 
tested this on an empty collection and test database it worked.

```
> db.serverStatus().metrics.ttl
{ "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0), "passes" : NumberLong(823) }
```

So I suspect that it will not delete this entry because there are other entries in the collection which do not have this field. Or is the problem something else?

Comment: That is not how a TTL index and removal works. It is actually a property set in the index based on a set period of time passing from a specified date field present in the document ( and indexed field ). See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Comment: @BlakesSeven well, according to the log the OP attached, he did actually follow the documentation. `{ expireAfterSeconds: 1, name: "expireAt_1", key: { expireAt: 1 } }`. It looks like you didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko It looks like the OP and yourself have not read the documentation correctly since the TTL process only runs "once every 60 seconds", thus allowing up to two minutes for an actual deletion to take place. The 1 second specified clearly expresses that the document is expected to be immediately removed, which is in contrast to all documentation that says is it not. Therefore, this is not a well researched question.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I was referring to what you said: *"It is actually a property set in the index based on a set period of time passing from a specified date field present in the document (and indexed field)"*. The OP obviously knows this, so your statement was neither necessary nor helpful. What you just said about the TTL process running once every 60 seconds, though, could be the actual reason of the OP's problem. See, if you were actually *attempting* to help by answering the question (which you did not read carefully), you would mention this in your first comment. But helping is not your goal.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Commentary is for clarification to the OP. The clarification here is "read the documentation". Which has clearly not been done by design of the the data and expectations. Also please don't upvote just because you saw a downvote. The question is not well researched or presented and as such does not meet the criteria. I'm saying this to the OP. You seem to be arguing with me in an unconstructive way. Reading the documentation helps the OP.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Your comments are not helpful, because you said *"That is not how a TTL index and removal works"*. That is not true and can only baffle the OP. This *is* how the feature works. It's just that there may be a delay of up to 60 seconds for the deletion (according to what you said). Also, this 60-second delay (TTL check interval) is *not* mentioned on the page you have linked. So your first comment is not only useless, it's harmful.

Comment: @falc410 How long have you tried to wait after inserting your document? Please read this: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-ttl/ — the background thread that removes the documents runs every 60 seconds, so just to make sure your approach **is not working**, try to wait for a couple of minutes.

Comment: I have read the documentation and tested this on another database where it performed as expected. Yes I want the entry to be removed as soon as the expireAt value is hit. According to the documentation I could have created the index with *expireAfterSeconds: 0* but this didn't seem to work, so I went with *expireAfterSeconds: 1*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"expireAt" : ISODate("2015-11-12T11:10:13.257Z")
```

The expiry date and time you have specified are in the future. As of the time of this answer, the expiry will occur in two minutes from now. This is why the document is still not deleted from your collection. But it will be deleted very soon.

The date/time format you have specified has a `Z` at the end, which enforces the UTC timezone.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Even though I run mongoDB and my Python Code locally and set the expireAt value using datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60) it actually created the datetime object not with my system time but with UTC timezone.

Comment: @falc410 I am glad I could help!

Comment: @VivekSingh Your comment is completely out of the scope of the question. Please create a separate question about that.

Comment: I have same problem with UTC and how to fix that ? Need to expireAt machine time